# Saving field values when going back and forth a visual force page in salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, fields

I have a problem with my visualforce page regarding salesforce1.

My page is a registration page that has multiple fields but there are 2 links below that redirects to the Terms and Private policy pages.

Now, If a user fills up all the fields and decides to read these pages then go back to the registration page the fields are kept but they aren't saved, I know this because there is a rendered attribute to read these fields so that the Terms and private policy pages would display pages depending on the user's preferred language(It is a picklist).

So is there a way to save fields as the user goes from one page to another but not necessarily to confirm the user's registration?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the platform cache to store the user session data.  Then retrieve it when you return to the page.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_org_examples.htm

Comment: so should i put this to a controller within a visualforce page ? or in the visualforce page itself

Comment: think you would want to do it within the controller.